# Resolve version conflicts when adding Angular Material to an Ionic Angular project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, angular-material, dependencies

I am working on an Ionic angular project. I'm trying to add Angular Material to use some of the included prebuilt UI components (dialog, date picker, etc). I've found a couple of guides on how to get started with Angular Material, but following either direction I'm unable to successfully run the CLI commands needed to add Angular Material to my project.

Here are links to the two guides I'm following:

**Using Angular Material in an Ionic Angular Project**

- https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-angular-material-how-to-install-material-and-use-its-components-in-ionic-app/

**Using Angular Material in an Angular Project**

- https://auth0.com/blog/creating-beautiful-apps-with-angular-material/

Following the first guide I ran `ng add @angular/material` and following the guide from the second link I ran `npm install @angular/material @angular/cdk`. Both commands returned similar errors on being unable to resolve dependencies

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: main@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@14.2.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"14.2.8" from @angular/common@14.2.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"14.2.8" from @angular/forms@14.2.8
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       peer @angular/forms@">=12.0.0" from @ionic/angular@6.3.4
npm ERR!       node_modules/@ionic/angular
npm ERR!         @ionic/angular@"^6.1.9" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"14.2.8" from @angular/platform-browser@14.2.8
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"14.2.8" from @angular/forms@14.2.8
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!         peer @angular/forms@">=12.0.0" from @ionic/angular@6.3.4
npm ERR!         node_modules/@ionic/angular
npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!     4 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, ...)
npm ERR!   peerOptional @angular/core@"14.2.8" from @angular/compiler@14.2.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler@"14.2.8" from @angular/compiler-cli@14.2.8
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!       peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^14.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@14.2.8
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!         dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^14.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       2 more (@ngtools/webpack, the root project)
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler@"14.2.8" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@14.2.8
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm ERR!       @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"^14.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!   7 more (@angular/forms, @angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @angular/material@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@14.2.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"14.2.10" from @angular/animations@14.2.10
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     peer @angular/animations@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/material@14.2.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       @angular/material@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/animations@"14.2.10" from @angular/platform-browser@14.2.10
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!       @angular/platform-browser@"^14.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       2 more (@angular/material, @angular/forms)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/noah.jackson/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/noah.jackson/.npm/_logs/2022-11-14T16_01_20_307Z-debug-0.log
```

This error came from the `npm install` command. The `ng add` error was the same except instead of `Could not reslove dependency: @angular/material@"*" from the root project` it says `Could not resolve dependency: @angular/material@"14.2.7" from the root project`

Also here's my package.json - if that helps

```
{
  "name": "main",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "4.4.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "4.0.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.1.9",
    "ionicons": "^6.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Any advice on how to resolve this issue would be great. Or general advice on how to prevent dependency issues like this.

Comment: Try with the -legacy-peer-deps flag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue last week with some other packages having conflicts with angular 14 (because it's required for angular material), I ended up removing some of them entirely (like ngx-marquee) since they are not compatible yet with angular 14, and using a combination of commands including `npm install` and `npm update` with `--legacy-peer-deps` to finally fix it, but I think the most important part was updating angular with ng update, I recommend you try that as well. like this

```
ng update @angular/core
```

Comment: This worked for me, I just needed to run "ng update @angular/core" then I was able to install Angular Material with "ng add @angular/material".